# Good introduction to free theorems

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I stumbled upon a nice idea of [free theorems](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi?help) in functional language. However, the only resource I was able to find is Wadler's article "[Theorems for Free](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/99370.99404)". It's quite good but it definitely not a tutorial and hard for me to get through (I understood about half of it and it required for me to spend quite a lot of time). Can you recommend me another article or tutorial which is oriented towards a software developer familiar with functional programming instead of hard core functional language researcher?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~jv/free-slides.pdf

http://daniel.yokomizo.org/2011/12/understanding-higher-order-code-for.html

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1203.pdf

(Also in typeclassopedia Section 3.3)

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-theorems-seq

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-theorems-counterexamples

Comment: First link is dead :(

Comment: I think the slides from the first link can now be found here: http://www.janis-voigtlaender.eu/free-slides.pdf

Comment: https://youtu.be/DSyZ6jnMJYg  "Why Wadler's paper is hard to understand"