# hi :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following type signature in Haskell:

```
hi :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

I want to write a concrete implementation of it but I'm really struggling to understand where to start. I understand that hi takes a function (b -> c) which returns a function (a ->b) which finally returns a function (a -> c).

Can anyone show me an example of a concrete implementation? How do I know where to start with something like this and what goes on the left side of the definition?

Comment: What is the purpose of `hi`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One way to think of this is as a function that takes a `(b -> c)` and an `(a -> b)` and returns another function `(a -> c)`. So let's start with that

```
hi f g = undefined       -- f :: b -> c, g :: a -> b
```

We know that the return type has to be a function `(a -> c)` -

```
hi f g = \a -> undefined -- f :: b -> c, g :: a -> b
```

We now have something of type `a` on the right hand side, and we have a function `g :: a -> b` so a sensible thing to do (in fact, the only thing we can do) is to apply `g` to `a`

```
hi f g = \a -> g a       -- ok, this fails to typecheck...
```

The expression `g a` has type `b`, and `f :: b -> c`, and we want to end up with a `c`. So again, there's only one thing we can do -

```
hi f g = \a -> f (g a)
```

And this type checks! We now start the process of cleaning up. We could move the `a` to the left of the equality sign

```
hi f g a = f (g a)
```

And, if you happen to know about the composition operator `.` you could notice that it can be used here

```
hi f g a = (f . g) a
```

Now the `a` is redundant on both sides (this is called [eta reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion))

```
hi f g = f . g
```

and we can pull the `.` operator to the front of the expression by using its function form `(.)`

```
hi f g = (.) f g
```

Now the `g` and the `f` are both redundant (two more applications of eta reduction)

```
hi = (.)
```

So your function `hi` is nothing more than function composition.

Comment: Ugh, I don't think I understand this part: We now have something of type a on the right hand side, and we have a function g :: a -> b so a sensible thing to do (in fact, the only thing we can do) is to apply g to a - how can you just decide to apply g to a?

Comment: A very comprehensive answer! For FP enthusiasts, I'd add that «the only thing we can do for this type» is a very interesting property called a free theorem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421085/good-introduction-to-free-theorems)

Comment: @cookiemonster You have a thing of type `a`, and you have a function with the right type to be applied to things of type `a`, and when you have those two things it's up to you whether to apply the function or not (but in this case you have to do *something* and applying the function is the only thing the type system allows you to do, so ...)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor ok, I think that makes sense. How about this statement: "We now start the process of cleaning up. We could move the a to the left of the equality sign" - how can you just decide to move a? How is this possible?

Comment: @cookiemonster Because the two definitions `f a = e` and `f = \a -> e` mean the same thing, for any expression `e`. This kind of transformation (replacing one thing with another when they know they are equal) is called [equational reasoning](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/12/equational-reasoning.html) and is a very powerful approach to writing code.

Comment: To eliminate the typecheck-failing stage, we can write `hi f g = \a -> (\b -> undefined) (g a)` or `hi f g = const undefined (g a)` :)

Answer (score 5):

You read it wrong: The `->` operator is right-associative. Thus, your signature is: `(b->c) -> ((a->b) -> (a->c))`. So you can read it as : given a function from `b` to `c`, it returns a function that takes a function from `a` to `b` to finally returns a function from `a` to `c`.

From there, you should be able to resolve the exercise by yourself.