# Is there a term for pure functions with only one possible implementation?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm thinking of functions like the identity function:

```
val f : 'a -> 'a
let f x = x
```

the composition function:

```
val compose : ('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'c)
let compose f g x = f (g x)
```

or the applicative `map` function if the monadic `return` and `bind` functions are defined:

```
val return : 'a -> 'a t
val ( >>= ) : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t

val ( >>| ) : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b t
let ( >>| ) t f = t >>= fun x -> f x |> return
```

In each of these cases, there is exactly one pure function (ignoring equivalent representations of the same logic) that could be written to satisfy the function's type signature.

Is there a term for functions like this? And why is it that there can only be one implementation?

Comment: What's your definition of "equivalent representation"? Wouldn't any correct implementation of a pure function be equivalent to any other implementation then?

Comment: You'll want to have a look at *theorems for free*, see [these introductions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12421085/1048572). I don't know whether there is a term for this kind of functions, though.

Comment: @glennsl I mean in the sense of equivalent rewrites (using `|>` instead of parens, storing a value in a temporary variable, etc.). I think what I'm looking for is unique implementations based on type signatures. As a counterexample, the functions `val hd : 'a list -> 'a option` and `val tl : 'a list -> 'a option` are both pure functions, but this demonstrates that the type signature `'a list -> 'a option` has two valid implementations with different results, so this would not be an example of a signature I'm looking for.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the reference; I think I was looking for some combination of parametricity / free theorems. Is there some free theorem from parametricity that could derive e.g. the existence of a unique `compose` function? If you post that as an answer I'm happy to accept that.

Comment: Note that parametricity results only hold in a pure language, not if you can have side effects like state, I/O, exceptions, non-termination. E.g., in Ocaml, these are other functions of type `'a -> 'a`: `let f1 x = print "boo"; x`; `let f2 x = raise E`; `let rec f3 x = f3 x`

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Sure, I clarified that I'm looking for pure functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own theory of functions, where the abovementioned functions will have some special semantics,

```
type _ fn =
  | Ident : ('a -> 'a) fn
  | Compose : (('b -> 'c) fn -> ('a -> 'b) fn -> ('a -> 'c)) fn
  | Map : (('b -> 'c) fn -> ('a -> ('a -> 'c) -> 'c) fn -> ('a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'c)) fn
  | Gen : 'a -> 'a fn
```

The minimal semantics would be the reification of those abstractions into OCaml functions, i.e., the application function,

```
let rec app : type s. s fn -> s = function
  | Ident -> fun x -> x
  | Compose -> fun f g x -> app f (app g x)
  | Map -> fun ret bind x f -> app bind x (fun x -> app ret (f x))
  | Gen f -> f
```

Note, that the provided `app` function is stupid, as it is not using the knowledge of the functions semantics in `Compose` and `Map` applications, i.e., that `Map Ident Ident` is `Ident`,`Compose Ident x` is `x`, and many other identities which could be inferred from even such simple theory. This all is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Of course, this extra layer of indirection will be noticeable, as you can't write direct `Ident x`, but have to write `app Ident x` instead. As well as lift all regular functions into your theory, e.g.,

```
let 7 = app (Gen (+)) 3 4.
```