# How do the requirements for the instances of the Applicative type class relate to their implementations for Functor

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, applicative

According to Haskell's library documentation, every instance of the Applicative class must satisfy the four rules:

- **identity:** `pure id <*> v = v`
- **composition:** `pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)`
- **homomorphism:** `pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)`
- **interchange:** `u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u`

It then says that as a consequence of these rules, the underlying Functor instance will satisfy `fmap f x = pure f <*> x`. But since the method `fmap` does not even appear in the above equations, how exactly does this property follow from them?

Comment: There are extra constraint that `liftA2 f x y = f <$> x <*> y` and `(<*>) = liftA2 id`. Since `(<$>)` is `fmap`, it is thus mentioned.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But wouldn't `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` be true even if `liftA2` didn't exist? After all, you can define an instance in terms of `liftA2` and then `<$>` really doesn't appear in any of the definitions, but it'll still hold.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes but I tried to rewrite ```pure f <*> x``` using this rule and got ```pure f <*> x = liftA2 id (pure f) x = id <$> (pure f) <*> x = pure f <*> x``` which didn't bring me anywhere. The last equation follows from the requirement ```fmap id = id``` in the Functor class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update*: I've substantially expanded the answer.  I hope it helps.

#### "Short" answer:

For any functor `F`, there is a "free theorem" (see below) for the type:

```
(a -> b) -> F a -> F b
```

This theorem states that for any (total) function, say `foo`,  with this type, the following will be true for any functions `f`, `f'`, `g`, and `h`, with appropriate matching types:

> If `f' . g = h . f`, then `foo f' . fmap g = fmap h . foo f`.

Note that it is not at all obvious why this should be true.

Anyway, if you set `f = id` and `g = id` and use the functor law `fmap id = id`, this theorem simplifies to:

> For all `h`, we have `foo h = fmap h . foo id`.

Now, if `F` is also an applicative, then the function:

```
foo :: (a -> b) -> F a -> F b
foo f x = pure f <*> x
```

has the right type, so it satisfies the theorem.  Therefore, for all `h`, we have:

```
pure h <*> x
-- by definition of foo
= foo h x
-- by the specialized version of the theorem
= (fmap h . foo id) x
-- by definition of the operator (.)
= fmap h (foo id x)
-- by the definition of foo
= fmap h (pure id <*> x)
-- by the identity law for applicatives
= fmap h x
```

In other words, the identity law for applicatives implies the relation:

```
pure h <*> x = fmap h x
```

It is unfortunate that the documentation does not include some explanation or at least acknowledgement of this **extremely non-obvious** fact.

#### Longer answer:

Originally, the documentation listed the four laws (identity, composition, homomorphism, and interchange), plus two additional laws for `*>` and `<*` and then simply stated:

> The `Functor` instance should satisfy
>
> ```
> fmap f x = pure f <*> x
> ```

The wording above was replaced with the new text:

> As a consequence of these laws, the `Functor` instance for `f` will satisfy
>
> ```
> fmap f x = pure f <*> x
> ```

as part of [commit 92b562403](https://gitlab.haskell.org/danbroooks/ghc/commit/92b56240332082c6d337e9e59f8b3a3928f972d2) in February 2011 in response to a [suggestion](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-February/015964.html) made by Russell O'Connor on the libraries list.

Russell pointed out that this rule was actually implied by the other applicative laws.  Originally, he offered the following proof (the link in the post is broken, but I found a copy on archive.org).  He pointed out that the function:

```
possibleFmap :: Applicative f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
possibleFmap f x = pure f <*> x
```

satisfies the Functor laws for `fmap`:

> ```
> pure id <*> x = x {- Identity Law -}
>
> pure (f . g) <*> x
> = {- infix to prefix -}
> pure ((.) f g) <*> x
> = {- 2 applications of homomorphism law -}
> pure (.) <*> pure f <*> pure g <*> x
> = {- composition law -}
> pure f <*> (pure g <*> x)
> ```

and then reasoned that:

> So, `\f x -> pure f <*> x` satisfies the laws of a functor.
>   Since there is at most one functor instance per data type,
>   `(\f x -> pure f <*> x) = fmap`.

A key part of this proof is that there is only one possible functor instance (i.e., only one way of defining `fmap`) per data type.

When asked about this, he gave the following proof of the uniqueness of `fmap`.

> Suppose we have a functor `f` and another function
>
> ```
> foo :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> ```
>
> Then as a consequence of the free theorem for `foo`, for any `f :: a -> b`
>   and any `g :: b -> c`.
>
> ```
> foo (g . f) = fmap g . foo f
> ```
>
> In particular, if `foo id = id`, then
>
> ```
> foo g = foo (g . id) = fmap g . foo id = fmap g . id = fmap g
> ```

Obviously, this depends critically on the "consequence of the free theorem for `foo`".  Later, Russell realized that the free theorem could be used directly, together with the identity law for applicatives, to prove the needed law.  That's what I've summarized in my "short answer" above.

#### Free Theorems...

So what about this "free theorem" business?

The concept of free theorems comes from a paper by Wadler, "Theorems for Free".  Here's a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12421085/7203016) that links to the paper and some other resources.  Understanding the theory "for real" is hard, but you can think about it intuitively.  Let's pick a specific functor, like `Maybe`.  Suppose we had a function with the following type;

```
foo :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
foo f x = ...
```

Note that, no matter how complex and convoluted the implementation of `foo` is, that same implementation needs to work for all types `a` and `b`.  It doesn't know anything about `a`, so it can't *do* anything with values of type `a`, other than apply the function `f`, and that just gives it a `b` value.  It doesn't know anything about `b` either, so it can't *do* anything with a `b` value, except maybe return `Just someBvalue`.  Critically, this means that the structure of the computation performed by `foo` -- what it does with the input value `x`, whether and when it decides to apply `f`, etc. -- is entirely determined by whether `x` is `Nothing` or `Just ...`.  Think about this for a bit -- `foo` can inspect `x` to see if it's `Nothing` or `Just someA`.  But, if it's `Just someA`, it can't learn anything about the value `someA`: it can't use it as-is because it doesn't understand the type `a`, and it can't do anything with `f someA`, because it doesn't understand the type `b`.  So, if `x` is `Just someA`, the function `foo` can only act on its `Just`-ness, not on the underlying value `someA`.

This has a striking consequence.  If we were to use a function `g` to change the input values out from under `foo f x` by writing:

```
foo f' (fmap g x)
```

because `fmap g` doesn't change `x`'s `Nothing`-ness or `Just`-ness, this change as no effect on the structure of `foo`'s computation.  It behaves the same way, processing the `Nothing` or `Just ...` value in the same way, applying `f'` in exactly the same circumstances and at exactly the same time that it previously applied `f`, etc.

This means that, as long as we've arranged things so that `f'` acting on the `g`-transformed value gives the same answer as an `h`-transformed version of `f` acting on the original value -- in other words if we have:

```
f' . g = h . f
```

then we can trick `foo` into processing our `g`-transformed input in exactly the same way it would have processed the original input, as long as we account for the input change after `foo` has finished running by applying `h` to the output:

```
foo f' (fmap g x) = fmap h (foo f x)
```

I don't know whether or not that's convincing, but that's how we get the free theorem:

> If `f' . g = h . f` then `foo f' . fmap g = fmap h . foo f`.

It basically says that because we can transform the input in a way that `foo` won't notice (because of its polymorphic type), the answer is the same whether we transform the input and run `foo`, or run `foo` first and transform its output instead.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I have not yet gone through everything you referenced, but I think I got the basic idea. So if I understand correctly, the free theorems are established based on how you can define functions in Haskell, and since all functions must be defined using a certain syntax, they must have some certain properties. However, if I were to define a function externally (e.g. in C), could I then maybe use the FFI and inspect the structures of its arguments, and thus define a function that violates the free theorems?

Comment: Yes, the above assumes that `fmap` doesn't "cheat".  If you did want to cheat, you wouldn't need to use the FFI and external functions.  If you just write an `fmap` that doesn't terminate, that violates the law; and you could undoubtedly use unsafe functions like `unsafeCoerce` to write an `fmap` that misbehaves.

Comment: I see. Although what I mean is that by "cheating" we could write two distinct implementations of `fmap` which both follow the law, that is they both satisfy `fmap id = id` and `fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g`, but yet also behave differently than each other. In this case, an implementation that doesn't terminate wouldn't count, since it wouldn't satisfy `fmap id = id`.